# Strange CURL issue with a particular website SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, curl

I am trying to use CURL to get web pages from a paricualr website however it gives this error:

```
curl -q -v -A "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" https://www.saiglobal.com/ --output ./Downloads/test.html
....
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.saiglobal.com
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
> Accept: */*
> 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:11:53 --:--:--     0* OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104
* stopped the pause stream!
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:11:53 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
} [5 bytes data]
curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104
```

I am not sure what is going on. I can't find a lot of useful info regarding to the error message. On my Mac, the errorno is 60 instead of 104.

However, using Chrome on these machines can load the page without any issue. One of the machines' CURL version is 7.58.0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *".... with a particular website SSL certificate"* - the issue is not with a SSL certificate. The SSL handshake (which is the only part where the certificate is involved) is successfully done with the site and the error only occurs later. Error 104 is Connection Reset, i.e. the server closes the connection for some unknown reason.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so too and tried to use Google Bot user agent to see if it would make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the certificate of this site. From the debug output it can be clearly seen that the TLS handshake is done successfully and outside this handshake the certificate does not matter.

But, it can be seen that the site `www.saiglobal.com` is CDN protected by Akamai CDN and Akamai [features some kind of bot detection](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/cloud-security/bot-manager.jsp):

```
$ dig www.saiglobal.com
...
www.saiglobal.com.      45      IN      CNAME   www.saiglobal.com.edgekey.net.
www.saiglobal.com.edgekey.net. 62 IN    CNAME   e9158.a.akamaiedge.net.
```

This bot detection is known to use some heuristics in order to distinguish bots from normal browsers and detection of a bot might result in a status code 403 access denied or in a simple hang of the site - see [Scraping attempts getting 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247122/scraping-attempts-getting-403-error) or [Requests SSL connection timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187280/requests-ssl-connection-timeout).

In this specific case it seems to currently help if some specific HTTP headers are added, specifically `Accept-Encoding`, `Accept-Language`, `Connection` with a value of `keep-alive` and `User-Agent` which matches somehow `Mozilla`. Failure to add these headers or having the wrong values will result in a hang.

The following works currently for me:

```
$ curl -q -v \
   -H "Connection: keep-alive" \
   -H "Accept-Encoding: identity" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en-US" \
   -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0"  \
   https://www.saiglobal.com/
```

Note that this deliberately tries to bypass the bot detection. It might stop working if Akamai makes changes to the bot detection.

Please note also that the owner of the site has explicitly enable bot detection for a reason. This means that with deliberately bypassing the detection for your own gain (like providing some service based on scraped information) you might get into legal problems.